# Conditional formatting - Highlight words from a list if present in another list and vica versa

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a list of values in column A named "Our Keywords"
and another list of values from multiple columns from competitors named "Competitor keywords"

Using conditional formatting, how can I highlight the keywords that appear in "Competitor keyword" columns but not in "Our keywords" column. And vice versa keywords that are unique to the "our keywords" column.

e.g. problem:

[image]

e.g. desired result:

[image]

The words that appear in column 1 ONLY are highlighted green and words that appear in the competitor columns but NOT in column 1 are highlighted red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### green color:

- apply to range **A1:A** custom fx: `=FILTER(A1, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:E, A1)))`

#### red color:

- apply to range **B1:B** custom fx: `=FILTER(B1, NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A, B1)))`
- apply to range **C1:C** custom fx: `=FILTER(C1, NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A, C1)))`
- apply to range **D1:D** custom fx: `=FILTER(D1, NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A, D1)))`
- etc.

[image: 0]