# Google sheets - conditional formatting from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two spreadsheets (S1 and S2). I want to apply conditional formatting to column D from S1 such that:

- if text from cell D1, D2,... from S1 is present in column A from S2, a cell is colored green
- if text from cell D1, D2,... from S1 is not present in column A from S2, a cell is colored red

Could not get my mind around it, could you please help? I assume I must use a formula, but not sure how...

Answer (score 4):

Select S1!D:D and (i) apply 'standard' red fill, (ii) Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... *Custom formula is* and:

```
=match(D1,indirect("S2!A:A"),)
```

with green highlighting and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! Worked  beautifully. 
How would you do NOT match?

Comment: Edit: This worked for me: 
NOT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Settings!D:D"),E2))

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna check this answer: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/54910481/5632629**

and to reference another sheet in conditional formatting you will need to use `INDIRECT()` - **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126045/186471**